# Laravel updateOrCreate - 1062 Duplicate entry

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel, eloquent

Есть такая таблица:

```
Schema::create('open_orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('orderID');
            $table->primary('orderID');
            ...
            $table->string('transactTime');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Периодически нужно синхронить в нее данные использую updateOrCreate:

```
$active_orders = $this->api->getOpenOrders();
        foreach ($active_orders as $order)
        {
            Orders::updateOrCreate([
                'orderID' => $order['orderID'],
                ...                   
                'transactTime' => $order['transactTime']
            ]);
        }
```

Итого, первый раз запись создается, а со второго:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '0b357043-4699-83d8-7118-c5a369b3ef75' for key 'PRIMARY'...

Подскажите, что я делаю не так, ведь после первой вставки, если запись существует то ее должно просто обновлять...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации же написано всё:

> If the model can not be found in the database, a record will be
>   inserted with the attributes from the first parameter, along with
>   those in the optional second parameter.

Так же это написано в [API](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_updateOrCreate):

> Create or update a record matching the attributes, and fill it with
>   values.

В вашем случае нужно `orderID` только оставлять в первом параметре, остальные выносить во второй параметр:

```
Orders::updateOrCreate(['orderID' => $order['orderID']],
[
   ...                   
   'transactTime' => $order['transactTime']
]);
```

В таком случае будет поиск только по `orderID` и метод будет работать правильно.

Comment: Спасибо! Работает.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего PRIMARY ключ не меняется, но и из-за того что меняется хоть одно поле  в массиве у `updateOrCreate`, функция пытается создать новую запись, а PRIMARY ключ повторяется.

Понять как работает метод изнутри помогут две ссылки:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L428
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L394